# First Byte Time is slow after SSL installation

Tags: https

This is the first time I try to install SSL for one of my clients but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is without SSL: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180208_2W_13870833ff7ddff2762c99b657acd43c/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1
and here is with SSL: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180212_E1_8a48e92b57b4f494ba988fcfcc36425f/2/details/#waterfall_view_step1

As you can see the First Byte Time went from A to F and takes 1-2 seconds to deal with it. Pingdom shows similar results.

Any suggestions? I've tried getting a new SSL certificate didn't help. OpenSSL, etc are up-to-date and the server is on Ubuntu 14.04 with apache 2.4.7

Comment: When I upgraded one of my servers to Ubuntu 17.10 from 17.04 the SSL handshake started taking 8 to 10 seconds for each request.   I never did figure out the issue and I ended up retiring that server.   Since 14.04 is so old it might just be time for an upgrade.

Comment: This might help: [Apache SSL Handshake Slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/818107/apache-ssl-handshake-slow) on ServerFault.

Comment: Is it a VM? Could it be related to slowness in acquiring randomness?